# Emacs : install a package with melpa on windows

Tags: emacs, melpa

I am trying to install a package with emacs melpa package manager.
The github page says that the package [multiple-cursors](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el#installation) is available with melpa.
But when I try to install or list this package using `M-x package-install multiple-cursors`, the package is not found.

I am using  emacs version 24.5.1 on windows. I have tried to add the following lines to my init.el file :

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/"))
```

What's wrong ? How shall I proceed to install this package ?

Comment: have you tried a `package-refresh-contents` before? Do you find it in `package-list-packages`?

Comment: that's was it ! package-refresh-contents makes the job, the package is now successsfully installed ! Thanks greetings ! ben